# How parse a string into two strings

Tags: python

How do I parse a string of the form "some words [branch] (https:// url)" into two strings: "some words [branch]" and "https://url"

In my case it is about the part "Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master] (https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master).

My piece of code:

```
headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    payload = { 
        "payload": {
            "summary": body['sections'][0]['activityTitle'],
            "severity": "critical",
        },
```

and json:

```
"body": 
    "{\"sections\":
        [
            {\"activityTitle\":\"Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master](https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master)\"}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I think you're asking: how do I parse a string of the form `"some words [branch](https://url)"` into two strings: `"some words [branch]"` and `"https://url"`.

Comment: @jarmod Yes that's exactly what i mean!

Comment: Update your question to add clarification on what you are asking for, and that will re-open the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex (`re` module) to solve it

```
import re

text="Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master](https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master)"

match = re.search(r'(.*?\])\s*\((.*?)\)', text)

if match:
    message = match.group(1)
    url = match.group(2)
    
    print (message)
    print(url)
```

Output:

> Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master]
>
> https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master

This code assumes that the message will be something of this format `<some text>[<again some text>](<url>)`

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions are very complicated (but that's my own opinion), so here an example without importing any modules:

```py
s = "Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master] (https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master)"
phrase, url = s.split(" (") #splits the string here ^^
url = url.strip(")") # gets rid of the closing parenthesis                                          ^
print(phrase)
print(url)
```

Output:

```py
Thomas Moga pushed to branch [master]
https://gitlab.com/thomas.moga/my-project/commits/master
```